# Latex: How do I make the text fill out the whole body so that the geometry bottom margin works?

Tags: latex, margin

I am trying to format a pdf doc in Latex using texmaker. I would like the bottom margin to be 2cm, but the text does not reach the end of the body so that this "gap" adds to the bottom margin and makes it too large. I don't really understand why it works for every other of the three margins but not for bottom margin. How do I make the text end exactly in-line with the body?

I have tried to configure the footer option, e.g. by using footskip=0pt, includefoot in geometry, in- or decrease the bottom margin but nothing has helped so far. Here is the preamble I used:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=40mm, bottom=20mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{xyz}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\headsep=15mm
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{showframe}
\footskip=0pt
```

I enabled showframe. I expected the distance between the end of the page and the last line of text to be 2cm but instead it is 2.5cm if I measure it. Also, there is a line in between the body and the end of the page that seems to represent the header. I expected this to by inside the body as well due to "includeheadfoot".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the geometry package to make reasonable calculations you must not mess with parameters like `\headsep=15mm` or  `\footskip=0pt` afterwards.

Also you should not ignore warnings about too small values for headheight and footheight.  The fancyhdr package will try to correct your mistake, but of course these corrections are unknown to the geometry package. So instead of relying on the automatic changes from the fancyhdr package, better set the foot and headheight appropriately.

As the footer is empty anyway, I suggest to only include the head into the text area.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=40mm, bottom=20mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, includehead,showframe,headheight=14.5pt,headsep=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{xyz}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
%\headsep=15mm
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
%\footskip=0pt

\flushbottom

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This has worked well, except I need the margin between the header and the beginning of the text at the top to be 1.5cm. That is why I used `\headsep=15mm`. Is there any way to keep this without messing with the bottom margin?